# src folder in sketch structure and include library from subfolder

Tags: arduino-ide, library

My Arduino/PlatformIO libraries folder

```
libraries
└── cleaner_robot
    └── TB6612_Dual
        ├── tb6612_dual.h
        └── tb6612_dual.cpp
```

I used this code to innclude it:

```
#include <TB6612_Dual/tb6612_dual.h>
```

But the compilation has errors like "undefinded variables, undefinded reference,...etc"

This is my sketch folder

```
Cleaner_Robot
└── src
    └── TB6612_Dual
        ├── tb6612_dual.cpp
        └── tb6612_dual.h
```

If i use this code, all is ok

```
#include "src/libs/TB6612_Dual/tb6612_dual.h"
```

So the question is how to include if header file is in a sub folder of a folder in libraries folder of Arduino/PlatformIO ?, i has searched for many things, but cant help. 
I also read about src folder allowed in Arduino, but where can find an official announcement/manual for this structure ?, cant find much about this

Thanks  :)

Comment: You're using PlatformIO? Maybe you should ask on a PlatformIO forum?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/libraries#toc5 -|- https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5:-Library-specification

Answer (score 1):

I could include header files in subfolder after including root header file.

```
#include <TB6612_Dual.h>
#include <TB6612_Dual/tb6612_dual.h>
```

```
TB6612_Dual
└── src
    ├── TB6612_Dual.h << Add this empty file.
    └── TB6612_Dual
        ├── tb6612_dual.cpp
        └── tb6612_dual.h
```

Examples:

- [utils_asukiaaa/examples/string/string.ino](https://github.com/asukiaaa/utils_asukiaaa/blob/d3e59913ba2bcb2f6866865791baa71592b01456/examples/string/string.ino#L1-L2)
- [utils_asukiaaa/src/utils_asukiaaa/string.h](https://github.com/asukiaaa/utils_asukiaaa/blob/d3e59913ba2bcb2f6866865791baa71592b01456/src/utils_asukiaaa/string.h)
- [utils_asukiaaa/src/utils_asukiaaa/string.cpp](https://github.com/asukiaaa/utils_asukiaaa/blob/d3e59913ba2bcb2f6866865791baa71592b01456/src/utils_asukiaaa/string.cpp)
- [utils_asukiaaa/src/utils_asukiaaa.h](https://github.com/asukiaaa/utils_asukiaaa/blob/d3e59913ba2bcb2f6866865791baa71592b01456/src/utils_asukiaaa.h)